# Не могу скачать месячные котировки я yahoo finance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, анализ-данных

Почему мне не удается скачать месячные котировки с яху? Interwal = 'm' - попробовал несколько вариантов и с дополнительными пакетами - не выходит, этот самый логичный пока, но не работает. freq='W-WED' и прочие тоже не выходят.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb

tickers_fn = r'C:/Users/II/Downloads/1.txt'
with open(tickers_fn) as f:
    stocklist = f.read().splitlines()

p = wb.DataReader(stocklist, 'yahoo', '2007-01-01', interwal = 'm')

for ticker in p.minor_axis:
    p.loc[:, :, ticker].dropna().to_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/{}_data.csv'.format(ticker))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE: 2020-06-08**

Пример внизу, который замечательно работал для старых версий `pandas` и `pandas-datareader` не будет работать с современными версиями этих библиотек.

**Внимание:** [в этом ответе я объяснил почему это больше не работает и как можно переписать устаревший код...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138064/211923)

---

**Устаревший пример:**

Попробуйте так (пример кода, который работал с версиями `pandas` и `pandas-datareader`, которые были актуальными в феврале 2017 года):

```
p = wb.get_data_yahoo(stocklist, '2007-01-01', interval='m')

for ticker in p.minor_axis:
    p.loc[:, :, ticker].dropna().to_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/{}_data.csv'.format(ticker))
```